# Disable winform button on sheet Activate event

Tags: vb.net

I want to set a buttons property to Enable = false when a worksheet activates.  I wrote what I thought was a pretty straight forward code:

```
    Private Sub dsbEmployeeBoard_ActivateEvent() Handles Me.ActivateEvent

    Dim NavForm As New frmNavigation
    NavForm.btnMoveForward.Enabled = False

End Sub
```

However, when the sheet activates my button does not disable. Am I missing something? The buttons default enable property is set to True and no other code is controlling this property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.Check event is trigger.

2.Check enabled is false after assign.

3.Maybe need refresh the form.